# Understanding the input characteristics of an RF power transistor (2SC2237)

Tags: transistors, rf, impedance-matching

I've had this 2SC2237 RF power transistor from Mitsubishi for quite some time and I've finally found a project for it.  The datasheet can be found [here](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/24/MITSUBISHI/2SC2237.html).  The first thing I need to do is figure out its input impedance at its specified operating frequency, which would seem to be 175MHz.

Unfortunately, the datasheet is not as informative as it could be and I don't see any chart that gives input impedance vs frequency, smith chart or any RF characteristics really.  What is given is this test circuit designed for 175MHz and I suspect that the network at the base of the transistor is designed to transform the 50 ohm source to the impedance of the transistor at f0.

[image]

To my untrained eye, it looks like a pi-network and if I take the median value of the trimmers and work out the various impedances at 175MHz I get the following equivalent pi-network (using this [tool](https://chemandy.com/calculators/matching-pi-attenuator-calculator.htm)):

[image]

I've obviously made a mistake, as the input impedance looking into the network is in the region of 10 ohms, whereas the output impedance is closer to 50 (which is actually the opposite of what I'd expect!).  Can anyone help me understand this network better and point out where I went wrong?  Regards.

Comment: A few comments to make ... Have you contacted Mitsubishi to ask for the S parameters for this component ? They may have it. Otherwise one way to obtain the input impedance is to measure it with a network analyser at a given bias that you require, and over the frequency range of interest. If no real data is available then perhaps choosing a different part from another vendor that does provides more information is also a good option to make your life easier ...

Comment: Agree with citizen.  This is not a very well characterized part if it's really intended to be used in a RF application.  Nothing about performance vs frequency, except for the marketing hype in the intro paragraph.  All the electrical parameters and performance charts seems to for DC operation.

Comment: @citizen and SteveSh all good points.  My intention is to glean as much as I can from the ds and then let the nano-vna loose on it (using the method you mentioned citizen).  That said, lets ignore the failings of the datasheet (need to be careful with the sh syllable there:-). Where have I gone wrong with my network understanding, just for future reference.

Comment: You're using a resistive attenuator tool to work out what's happening with a filter. Reactances don't work like that. Simply putting the magnitude of the reactance into a resistive attenuator will not give you a filter response. Use a proper simulator.

Comment: @Neil_UK That's true, but I'm not really looking for the response as such. I'm looking for the impedance looking into the network from the transistor side at a particular frequency (175MHz).  You're right, if I was looking for the overall response, I'd choose a different method.

Comment: @Neil_UK Ah wait, maybe I misunderstood your comment.  Are you saying that even at a particular frequency, simply using the magnitude of the component reactance like I've done will not suffice.  Maybe there are phase relationships between the components that I'm not capturing by doing what I'm doing, is that the issue?

Comment: @Buck8pe `maybe there are phase relationships between the components`  ...  Oh yes. Like the fact that an inductive and a capacitive reactance can cancel, either partially or fully, each other out, whereas resistors can only ever add.

Comment: This datasheet https://www.pcs-electronics.com/schematics/2sc2237.pdf contains informations about input impedance @175 MHz

Comment: Other helpfull tools https://www.broadcom.com/appcad

Comment: @Buck8pe This can be also of interest for you (Chart Smith and applications) http://amanogawa.com/